# Is it possible to obtain a PPL after having a brain surgery?

Tags: faa, medical

I am a 24 year old who has always aspired to become a pilot. I've decided to eventually get a private pilot's license so I can fly just for fun. However, a few months ago I was diagnosed with brain tumor which I had removed. There were no complications, I have never had any seizures, I'm not epileptic, etc. As far as I am concerned (and my doctors as well), I am now in perfect health.

With this in mind, is it still possible for me to obtain a PPL?

Comment: With some aircraft types,I'd say that brain surgery is a pre-requisite!  Seriously, good luck.  You need a medical anyway and the examining doctor will make that decision or take it higher for you.  My advice is to get the medical done first; you need it to solo anyway.  I'm sure it will be fine.

Comment: Update : I have my Class 1 with an OML restriction. But this restriction may be removed 3 years after the surgery if no complications occur. And I had my CPL(A) by the way :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [AOPA](http://www.aopa.org/)'s medical guru on their discussion board (members only, or I would link to an example) it is possible to get a medical certificate following a tumor removal but only after a 5-year wait and a battery of tests.

But having said that, medical issues are very individual and the FAA's [AME guidance](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/app_process/exam_tech/item46/amd/cd/) suggests that one year is enough in some cases. In the end the only way to get a definite answer is to find a good AME who can review your case in detail and advise you. Note that standard advice is to schedule a consultation first, rather than go straight for the actual flight medical.

Disclaimer: I'm not a doctor or AME and I have no idea how brains work :-)

Comment: Thank you for this! Looking at that FAA page you linked, it would seem that I could be considered "favorably" and have to wait only one year.

Comment: @Deusdies I hope so, but please make sure that you get a consultation first. If you get an actual medical test then it can only end in a pass or fail, and a fail will complicate all your future tests. It's much better to get everything lined up properly with your AME and then do it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in the United States and you have never been denied an FAA medical certificate or had your medical revoked and you have a driver's license, then you can fly as a sport pilot in light sport aircraft.  There are some limitations compared to a PPL, the major ones being that you are limited to one passenger and daytime VFR operations.

If you decide to later move up to a PPL, then you will have to get a medical.  There is some risk, though.  If you attempt to get a medical and are denied, you will also lose your sport pilot priviliges.

Comment: Keep in mind the drivers license lets you *self-certify* yourself as medically able to fly (it is not a blanket pass to fly). If you are aware of an issue that would preclude your ability to obtain an FAA medical or otherwise be unsafe to fly, you cannot self-certify regardless if you haven't applied and failed a medical exam. You are held to the same standards you just have the ability to be the certifier rather than an AME. Advising someone to be a sport pilot to avoid taking and failing a 3rd class exam is bad advice.

Comment: My reading of Part 61 is that the light-sport medical requirements are a little more strict than this. Specifically, if you have *ever applied* for a medical certificate, then you need to be issued a medical certificate before you meet the medical requirements for light-sport aircraft. This means that if you're flying LSAs using a driver's license to meet the medical requirement, and you apply for a medical certificate, the act of applying causes you to be ineligible until your application is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I have a PPL license and I was on the way to obtain a CPL license when I had a seizure.
After many tests it came out that I had a cavernous angioma in my brain on the left temporal lobe anterior. It had bleed outside causing the seizure. 
After removal of the cavernoma with brain incision, I had no other seizures and no complications and I went to see the AME. 
I had lots of EEGs, MRIs and the AMEs decision is giving back my Class I certificate for at least 1 year after the surgery.
Neurology is decreasing the medication now and after medication is finished I will have few other checks. 
If everything goes OK, I will have my Class I medical license back with an OML restriction (most probably).

This may give you lots of information about your situation : https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/8984_cons_en.pdf

I hope this helps and don't give up. :)

Note : I have my Class 1 with OML and CPL(A) now.